# Create schedule task in default user account

Tags: scheduled-tasks

I have a application which will create a scheduled task in win7 for the current user.

There is a special requirement that says this scheduled task should be created automatically for each newly created user. Is there any way to achieve this?

I'm thinking about using the window default user profile to achieve this, but I don't know how to do it.